# How to find out upload/post time of an special website URL?

Tags: web-search

Often when searching for information i hit the problem, that the author of an article/website/blog post doesnt give out a date.

Is there any way (maybe special meta search engine, web-archives, use of google search operators to find out at least on which month & year a website URL was uploaded?

thx

Comment: https://www.webnots.com/how-to-find-last-updated-date-of-a-web-page/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puttin

```
javascript:alert(document.lastModified)
```

in the adress bar of a browser with loaded page pops up a date and time. Where this time data is coming from i have no idea, probably time html or php file was created on server. On the other way i thought javascript cannot access filesystem, but im no expert...

Still curious if someone knows a reliable method of finding out when a specific .html site was created as i find it useful for enquiry.